# Flash CS6 Large Image Slow Compile Time

Tags: actionscript-3, compilation, flash-cs6

I have just started a project so I have a few lines of code that don't do much yet. I have imported my images as layers from a PSD file which was quite large. When I compiled the SWF for testing it takes longer than it normally does. I tried all the normal things like compression, turning off warnings mode and the rest but nothing has helped.

Also my images are in a MovieClip symbol and some of the frames have Tweens on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash CS6 has to parse the PSD to get images from there, and this apparently takes a lot of time. Also it's possible that Flash CS6 is programmed to parse the single PSD **once per asset**, making things even more ugly. You'd better export those layers as PNG and import them into your project instead of the PSD.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, much quicker, I merged the layers that I could and made my image a bit lower res which I think made it go a little quicker (it was 1000x3000)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of embedding images you could export layers as png -files and load them at runtime. I think that is better way to go.. your flash is smaller, (loads faster) and it's easy to update images when needed.